# CoreData - inconsistent model with an association that doesn't exist

Tags: core-data

I'm trying to figure out a user's crash they're experiencing on their device.  I have a `post` model that has-one `image`, with the delete-rule rule set to nullify.  Trying to access `post.image` results in NSObjectInaccessibleException.  If I look at the sqlite database backing it, the `post` row references an `image` with id 11, but that particular row doesn't exist in the corresponding `images` table. (There is an image with id=12, so presumably the one with id=11 did exist at some point...)

I'm struggling to see how this might have occurred - any guesses at scenarios that can result in an association not getting cleaned up?

Comment: Looks to me like somehow the image object was not saved. How do you manage your context stacks? Child+parent? Confinement?

Comment: It's a child-parent setup.  Post & image are initially created in a disposable child context, but are saved to the parent context once the user first saves the post.

Comment: But are they also persisted to disk? I fear the problem is, they were not persisted to the coordinator (i.e. calling `save:` on the topmost context), and trying to access the objects causes a crash.

Comment: I guess... Though one (the post) was definitely persisted from the topmost context, complete with foreign-key reference to the image.  I assume the image was also saved at the same time, but later deleted - I'm not 100% sure though

Comment: Do you have inverse relationships? And what are the delete rules between the relationships?

Comment: Yep - it's set to nullify

Comment: Inaccessible objects almost always mean that you either deleted the object or failed to save it somehow. Without code I can't guess at why that's happening, but it's extremely likely that one of these is happening.